# Nginx not everyone can connect

Tags: nginx, php-fpm

Not all connections to our page work. Many people can connect only after like 10 trys..
The page keep load and then it shows a connection times out error.
I already tryed much but nothing helped.

Nginx config:

```
    user  www www;

worker_processes 4;

error_log  /home/wwwlogs/nginx_error.log  warn;

pid        /usr/local/nginx/logs/nginx.pid;

#Specifies the value for maximum file descriptors that can be opened by this process.
worker_rlimit_nofile 8192;

events
    {
        use epoll;
        worker_connections 4096;
        multi_accept on;
    }

http
    {
        include       mime.types;
        default_type  application/octet-stream;

        server_names_hash_bucket_size 128;
        client_header_buffer_size 64k;
        large_client_header_buffers 4 64k;
        client_max_body_size 10m;
        client_body_buffer_size 256m;

        sendfile on;
        tcp_nopush     on;

        keepalive_timeout 60;

        tcp_nodelay on;

        fastcgi_connect_timeout 300;
        fastcgi_send_timeout 300;
        fastcgi_read_timeout 300;
        fastcgi_buffer_size 256k;
        fastcgi_buffers 8 256k;
        fastcgi_busy_buffers_size 512k;
        fastcgi_temp_file_write_size 1024k;

        gzip on;
        gzip_min_length  2k;
        gzip_buffers     4 32k;
        gzip_http_version 1.0;
        gzip_comp_level 2;
        gzip_types       text/plain application/x-javascript text/css application/xml;
        gzip_vary on;
        gzip_proxied        expired no-cache no-store private auth;
        gzip_disable        "MSIE [1-6]\.";

        #limit_zone  crawler  $binary_remote_addr  10m;

        server_tokens off;
        #log format
        log_format  access  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
             '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
             '"$http_user_agent" $http_x_forwarded_for';

server
    {
        listen      127.0.0.1:8080;
        server_name www.lnmp.org;
        index index.html index.htm index.php;
        root  /home/wwwroot/default;


        location ~ .*\.(php|php5)?$
            {
                try_files $uri =404;
                fastcgi_pass  unix:/tmp/php-cgi.sock;
                fastcgi_index index.php;
                include fcgi.conf;
            }

        location /statusdsd {
            stub_status on;
            access_log   off;
        }

        location ~ .*\.(gif|jpg|jpeg|png|bmp|swf)$
            {
                expires      30d;
            }

        location ~ .*\.(js|css)?$
            {
                expires      24h;
            }

        #access_log  /home/wwwlogs/access.log  access;
    }
include vhost/*.conf;
}
```

php-fpm conf:

```
[www]
listen = /tmp/php-cgi.sock

    user = www
    group = www
    pm = static
    pm.max_children = 8
    pm.start_servers = 2
    pm.min_spare_servers = 2
    pm.max_spare_servers = 6
    request_terminate_timeout = 100
    pm.max_requests = 2500
```

Would be nice if anyone got tipps.

Server stats:
8gb ram & 4 cores. 1000mbps connection.

Comment: You should provide us logs from nginx, other possibility is to run nginx in debug mode, but I wouldn't recommend to do this on highload website (this can be some test env)

Answer (score 1):

You're going to want to allow more than 8 php-fpm workers. Right now, you're only going to be able to process eight requests at a time, and with eight gigabytes of RAM to work with you've got plenty of space for more.

Comment: updated to 30 but nothing changed.

Comment: Time to start narrowing it down, then. What's your CPU and RAM usage like?

Comment: cpu usage 0.2% and ram still most free